# Any good reference for JQOM?

Tags: java, database, apache, jackrabbit

Apache Jackrabbit includes some sort of database/archive query mechanism called JQOM.  Where is a good place to start learning about what it is and how it works?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Jackrabbit is an implementation of the [JSR 170](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=170) and as of version 2.0 [JSR 283](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=283)
JQOM is part of the JSR283 spec.
A good start would be to read the spec. It's a long read but it's definitely worth it and usually contains some clear examples.

Jackrabbit itself is only fully compliant with the spec since the end of January (2010) so resources are scarce at the moment, but this should improve when adoption improves.

Comment: Since I have no idea what they are trying to accomplish, I would rather start out reading something more tutorial-like.  Is there anything out there like that?